# if statement ignored - php MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

On this site I'm building, people can reserve some tablets.
It first checks the MySQL database to see how many tablets are free, so no more tablets are reserved than possible.

However, after the form is submitted, the maximum ammount is checked, the error message is displayed, but they still are added to the database.

Example: Only 10 iOS-tablets are free, a user tries to reserve 15. The site show "too much iOS tablets, only 10 available" but still inserts 15 in the database.

Update: The statement that checks how much tablets are entered in the form and checks with the database:

```
if($_POST['ios'] > $ios) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Too much iOS tablet.. Max is " . $ios . "</span><br />";}
if($_POST['android'] > $android) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Too much Android tablets. Max is " . $android . "</span><br />";}
if($_POST['windows'] > $windows) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Too much Windows tablets. Max is " . $windows . "</span><br />";}
```

All other error-messages work correct.

Code:

```
<?
 //check reservations on date
  $sql = "SELECT SUM(ios) as iostotal,SUM(android) as androidtotal,SUM(windows) as windowstotal FROM reservaties WHERE '$datum' = datum";
  $check = mysqli_query($link,$sql) or die(mysql_error());         
    while ($free = mysqli_fetch_array($check)) {
    $ios = 15 - $free['iostotal']; 
    $android = 15 - $free['androidtotal'];
    $windows = 15 - $free['windowstotal'];
    }
?>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($_POST['ios'] == null) {$resios = 0;} else {$resios = $_POST['ios'];}
  if($_POST['android'] == null) {$resand = 0;} else {$resand = $_POST['android'];}
  if($_POST['windows'] == null) {$reswin = 0;}  else {$reswin = $_POST['windows'];}
  //Check for errors
  if($_POST['naam'] == null) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Gelieve een naam in te vullen</span><br />";}
  if($_POST['opleiding'] == 0) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Selecteer een opleiding</span><br />";}
//PROBLEM STARTS HERE
  if($_POST['ios'] > $ios) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal iOS tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $ios . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
  if($_POST['android'] > $android) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal Android tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $android . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
  if($_POST['windows'] > $windows) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Aantal Windows tablets overschreden. Maximum " . $windows . " tablets beschikbaar.</span><br />";}
//PROBLEM STOPS HERE
  if($_POST['terms'] != 'on') {echo "<span class=\"error\">Reglement moet aanvaard worden.</span><br />";}
  if($resios == 0 && $resand == 0 && $reswin == 0) {echo "<span class=\"error\">Er moet minstens 1 tablet gereserveerd worden</span>";}

  else {
    $query = "INSERT INTO reservaties(oplid,naam,datum,ios,android,windows) VALUES ('" . $_POST['opleiding'] . "','" . $_POST['naam'] . "','" . $datum . "','" . $resios . "','" . $resand . "', '" . $reswin . "')";
    if(mysqli_query($link,$query)) {
      echo "<p class=\"succes\">U hebt succesvol " . $resios . " iOS-tablets, " . $resand . " Android-tablets en " . $reswin . " Windows-tablets gereserveerd op " . $datum . "</p>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<p class=\"error\">Er is een fout opgetreden. Probeer opnieuw, of neem contact op met de <a href=\"mailto:mediatheek.kantienberg@arteveldehs.be\">Mediatheek</a>.</p>";}
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: you have million IF in your code which one is ignored ?? or we detect it by ourself ?

Comment: and you said `error message is displayed` why dont you post the error message also ?

Comment: If it was written in English I would help you out but having to figure out what is wrong with your code while having to read whatever language that is to decipher it, is a no no. Also I see no IF to check weather or not the amount of product wanted is available.

Comment: Added the correct statements. Sorry, forgot to extra copy-paste those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"However, after the form is submitted, the maximum amount is checked, the error message is displayed, but they still are added to the database."

as per your question, i have referred your whole code, `your problem is you are not stopping insertion of data while you are checking requested entries are less than of equal to`. you have to out insertion query into else criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try and implement this.

Comment: Now did a quick solution by setting the number to reserve to the maximum if the number posted is to much. But will certainly make my if-statements better, because it's very messy right now.